# How to use the NSUrlConnection for getting the data from web?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

In my application I want to use the `NSURLConnection` class. So please tell me how to use this one? This contain the lot of delegate methods, please tell me how to use them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Initiate the connection using

```
self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sampleurl/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection autorelease];
```

and you can catch the response in the connectionDidFinishLoading delegate method

```
#pragma mark - NSURLConnection Delegate Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
        //Getting your response string
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.responseData = nil;
    }
```

For your memory leak problem

Declare the response data in interface file

```
NSMutableData *_responseData;
```

with property as below

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *responseData;
```

and synthesize it

```
@synthesize responseData = _responseData;
```

Dont release it anywhere (We have used convenient constructors for allocation). We have already set it to nil in connectionDidFinishLoading method.

Comment: how to release the responsedata

Comment: set it to nil in connectionDidFinishLoading ( self.responseData = nil; )and release the ivar in dealloc method. ( [responseData release]; )

Comment: I got the 100% memory leak problem at self.responseData=[NSMutableData data];

Comment: This code should be fine. Have you released the responseString after using it. I haven't released it in the code. May be you are having the leak in response string.

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 5 and OS X 10.7  or later you can load data asynchronously using the following:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sampleurl/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
       completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse * response, NSData * data, NSError * error) {
           NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
           if(httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
               //your code to handle the data
           }
       }
];
```

Or if you want to do it synchronously (not recommended if you are loading large data as it will hang the application) (available in OS X 10.2+ and iOS 2.0+)

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sampleurl/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLResponse * response;
NSError * error;
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: A nice simple answer that did everything I wanted. Thanks!