# Objective C - objects not stored in array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

implementation file :

```
#import "MainTableViewController.h"
#import "JSON.h"

@interface MainTableViewController ()

@end

NSString *const APIKey = @"APIkey hidden on purpose";

@implementation MainTableViewController

- (void)searchFlickkrPhotos : (NSString *)text
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=%@&tags=%@&per_page=15&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", APIKey, text];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void) connection : (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(jsonString);
    NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];
    NSArray *photos = [[results objectForKey:@"photos"] objectForKey:@"photo"];
    for (NSDictionary *photo in photos)
    {
        NSString *title = [photo objectForKey:@"title"];
        [photoTitles addObject:(title.length > 0 ? title:@"Untitles")];
        NSString *photoURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.static.flickr.com/%@/%@_%@_s.jpg", [photo objectForKey:@"farm"], [photo objectForKey:@"server"], [photo objectForKey:@"id"], [photo objectForKey:@"secret"]];
        [photoSmallImageData addObject:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURLString]]];
        photoURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.static.flickr.com/%@/%@_%@_m.jpg", [photo objectForKey:@"farm"], [photo objectForKey:@"server"], [photo objectForKey:@"id"], [photo objectForKey:@"secret"]];
    [photoURLsLargeImage addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURLString]];
        NSLog(@"photoURLsLareImage: %@\n\n", photoURLString);
     }
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[photoSmallImageData count]]);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [photoURLsLargeImage count]]);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [photoTitles count]]);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        photoSmallImageData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        photoTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        photoURLsLargeImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView setRowHeight:80];
    [self searchFlickkrPhotos:@"iphone"];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [photoTitles count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[photoSmallImageData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[photoTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

header file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray  *photoTitles;         // Titles of images
    NSMutableArray  *photoSmallImageData; // Image data (thumbnail)
    NSMutableArray  *photoURLsLargeImage; // URL to larger image
}
@end
```

I just started objective c programming not very wrong ago, forgive me for any fundamental errors that i might have in my code.
Did i allocate and initialise the arrays in a wrong way or was my method of saving the objects into the array wrong?
And if possible pls tell me how can i improve my code.

Comment: init your mutablearray in viewdidload, or in initWithNibName:bundle or initWithCoder.  may be your init methods can are not be calling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading an object (view controller) from a .xib file or storyboard, the initialization that gets called is `initWithCoder:` rather than a plain `init`.  Try implementing that instead.

Answer (score 0):

At first, at

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

method your receive only part of a data, this method can be called multiple times while loading your request.

Data here is the newly available data. The delegate should concatenate the contents of each data object delivered to build up the complete data for a URL load.

All your data has been finished loading only when your delegate receives this message:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

It means that your should move your JSON parsing and table reloading code to this callback method.

You can read more about NSURLConnection usage here for example:

[How to use the NSUrlConnection for getting the data from web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483085/how-to-use-the-nsurlconnection-for-getting-the-data-from-web)

Comment: sorry, do you mind showing me how to rewrite the code?